# Sum range of month by quarters

Tags: google-sheets

I'm importing a range from another spreadsheet using `=IMPORTRANGE()` which results in the following:

[image]

I need to `sum()` for groups of three month (every quarter), i.e., sum Jan, Feb, Mar in column 1, Apr, May, Jun in column 2, and so on...

How do I accomplish this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data starts at col A and row 5 and extends to row 7 paste the below formula in column A and drag and autofill the formula across in the same row.

```
=sum(INDEX(transpose($A$5:$L$7),(column()-1)*3+1))+sum(INDEX(transpose($A$5:$L$7),(column()-1)*3+2))+sum(INDEX(transpose($A$5:$L$7),(column()-1)*3+3))
```

If your starting column is different from 1(Col A) then change the offset to the column number you are starting the formula at. So for column D you modify the below from

```
column()-1
```

to this

```
column()-4
```

The ways this works is to transpose the data array and select one column at a time using index, to be summed. The `(column()-1)*3+1,2,3` generates index for next three columns to be summed.

Answer (score 1):

```
=sum(offset($N5,0,(column()-19)*3,1,3))
```

where $N5 is the date for Jan. and "19" is the column() value for the starting column of the new, quarterly table.

Comment: Here's an example using your formula. I made it a bit more generic (that "19" could lead to issues): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13kSkbjlQSYH5DpvgHsGbo2w9Ot882EMpC3Nbj0xvJI4/edit#gid=0